# Sending data to Arduino Uno (w/ Ethernet shield) from Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, arduino, arduino-uno

Is there any way to send data from Parse to an Arduino Uno with an Ethernet shield? I'm totally in the dark on this one and can only find documentation to send data from the Arduino Uno to Parse which I was successfully able to accomplish.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a "web server" or just a server accepting tcp requests and by using a software to bridge Parse and Arduino that sends a specific call to the Arduino.

So you need to write a software that get the info from Parse, then send it over to the Arduino  like /something/happened